# How to use an variable of Object Observable inside another Observable subscribe function - RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have two observables of different types which emit two different types of Objects. But I need to update analytics on a successful login with userId and role. User Id is already set in viewModel login function call on successful login.

```
                       viewModel.login(emailId)
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .autoDisposable(scopeProvider)
                                .subscribe({ (role, images) ->
                                analyticsProvider.updateUser(mapOf(Constants.Role to role, 
Constants.userId to *NEED TO ENTER USER ID FROM OTHER OBSERVABLE HERE*)))
```

My Session Observable which emits User object.

```
 class SessionClass{
        private val user = BehaviorSubject.create<User>()
        override fun setUser(user: User) {
                this.user.onNext(user)
            }
         override fun getUser(): Observable<User> = user.hide()
    }
```

I tried to call `SessionClass().getUser().blockingFirst().userId` at that place but the phone gets hung at the login screen.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution does not work simply because you immediately instantiate a `SessionClass` and never call `setUser()`, so `getUser().blockingFirst()` will block forever. I will assume that you have an instance of `SessionClass` which will actually have `setUser()` called at some point.

The key to having access to the user there is to [combine](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables) the Observables. The appropriate choice in this situation is the [`zipWith`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#zipWith-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) operator. This will allow you to operate on the values from two sources at once. For example, your code might look something like this:

```
val session: SessionClass = TODO() // get an instance somewhere

viewModel.login(emailId)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .zipWith(session.getUser().firstOrError(), BiFunction { (role, images): Pair<Role, Images>, user: User -> Triple(role, images, user) })
    .autoDisposable(scopeProvider)
    .subscribe({ (role, images, user) ->
        analyticsProvider.updateUser(mapOf(Constants.Role to role, Constants.userId to user.userId))
    })))
```

Comment: Thanks Panda. Will give it a try. But I have a doubt. I used a slightly different approach. I used zip operator and created a Bi-function which returns an instance of a custom object I created containing all the fields. Is there a reason why zipWith is opted rather than zip?

Comment: And also `zipWith` is not being recognized after the autoDisposable :(

Comment: @ASN `a.zipWith(b, zipper)` is just like doing `Observable.zip(a, b, zipper)` except you can chain it so it can look nicer. Once `autoDisposable` is called, you can only `subscribe`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: apparently `viewModel.sessionManager().blockingGet().getUser()` is a `Observable<User>`. But `zipWith` is expecting a Single instead of an Observable

Comment: You can use one of the `first` operators to convert it to a `Single`.

Comment: But in this case what do I need to pass as default value to the `first` operator.